# LTRect and LTLine extraction - pdfminer

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

I am using pdfminer to extract line and rectangle objects in pdf documents but for some pdf's LTRect and LTLine objects are not getting identified even though there are lines and rectangles in it. Could you please suggest why these objects are not getting identified or what can be done to get these objects.

Comment: Have you figured out any solution?